# Why isn't there a common base for the standard library containers?

Tags: c++, stl, std

Just out of interest...

If I were to design a library of containers, I would surely derive them from a common base class, which would have (maybe abstract) declarations of methods like `size()` and `insert()` .

Is there a strong reason for the standard library containers not to be implemented like that?

Comment: It's an unnecessary abstraction. We have iterators for iterating, and many properties of specific containers can't be properly abstracted in a useful fashion.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In C++, inheritance is used for run-time polymorphy (read: run-time interface reuse). It comes with the overhead of a redirection via the vtable at runtime.

In order to have the same interface for multiple container classes (so that the API is predictable and algorithms can make assumptions), there's no need for inheritance. Just give them the same methods and you're done. The containers (and algorithms) in C++ are implemented as templates, which means that you get compile-time polymorphy.

This avoids any run-time overhead, and it is in line with the C++ mantra "Only pay for what you need".

Comment: You only have vtables when you have virtual methods. You don't pay anything when you use methods from a base class.

Comment: @Scharron: That's correct. However, when you ahve a base class, it's possible for clients to use a base class pointer to a derived class. Calling `delete` on that pointer should certainly also execute the destructor of the derived class - which means you need a virtual destructor. And then you have a vtable.

Comment: Totally right. The point of using the base class was to "factorize" things, so the base object could be hidden, and delete behaviour on base pointer could have been undefined. But that's ugly ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Java collections (which you probably have in mind) have a bunch of common methods implemented in `AbstractCollection`, that sit on top of the `size()` and `iterator()` methods implemented in the concrete class. Then IIRC there are more such methods in `AbstractList` and so on. Some subclasses override most of those methods, a few can get away with implementing little more than the required abstract methods. Some of the methods genuinely are implemented in common across most or all collections sharing an interface. For example the one that gives you a non-modifiable view is a total PITA to write, in my bitter experience.

C++ containers have a few member functions in common to all containers, pretty much none of which could be implemented the same way for all containers[*]. Where there are common algorithms that can be performed using an iterator (like `find`), they are free functions in `<algorithm>`, far from anywhere that inheritance gets a look-in.

There are also member functions common to all sequences, to all associative arrays, etc. But again for each of those concepts there isn't much in common between the implementations for different concrete data structures.

So ultimately in comes down to a question of design philosophy. Both Java and C++ have some code reuse in respect of containers. In C++ this code reuse comes through function templates in `<algorithm>`. In Java some of it comes through inheritance.

The main practical difference probably is that in Java your function can accept a `java.util.Collection` without knowing what kind of collection it is. In C++ a function template can accept any container, but a non-template function cannot. This affects the coding style of users, and is also informed by it - Java programmers are more likely to reach for runtime polymorphism than C++ programmers.

From an implementer's point of view, if you're writing the library of C++ containers then there is nothing to stop you from sharing private base classes between different containers in `std`, if you feel that will help reuse code.

[*] Now that `size()` is guaranteed `O(1)` in C++11, `empty()` could probably be implemented in common. In C++03 `size()` merely "should" be `O(1)`, and there were implementations of `std::list` that took advantage of this to implement one of the versions of `splice` in `O(1)` instead of the `O(n)` it would take to update the size.

Answer (score 1):

There is no good reason to introduce such base class. Who would benefit from it? Where would it be useful?

Algorithms that require a 'generic' interface use iterators. There is no common way of inserting elements to different containers. In fact, you cannot even insert elements to some containers.

Comment: don't forget the insert()s that can be templates.

Answer (score 1):

From another viewpoint: right now, if you use them in a generic way, the compiler has about all the information it can have, enabling thorough optimization. Thanks to template implementations.

Now, if for example both list and vector would implement an abstract OO interface like push_backable, and you would use an abstract pointer (push_backable*)->push_back(...) in your code, the compiler would lose a lot of information and thus opportunities for optimization.

These are typical operations that might appear in inner loops and you really want the maximal possible optimization for them. See also Frerich Raabe's answer.

Answer (score 0):

It would make sense if you could write code that is independent of the container you are using. But that's not the case. I recommend you to read this chapter *"Item 2: Beware the illusion of container-independent code"* of the book *Effective STL*.

Comment: For what it's worth, you *can* write code that is independant of the container - even without any inheritance at all. Just give every container a method with the same name (say, "empty") and hopefully the same semantic and you're done.